# Mapping Exsisting DataBase Tables to Entity Framework is causing many problems

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have already existing DataBase inside SQL server 2008 around (300 tables) so I faced the following problems when i try to create an entity framework .edmx file:

1. If I specify to map all the 300 tables at once, the visual Studio will hang.
2. So I decide to include only the tables which I currently need, then the mapping will work fine. But if after that I add a new table to them, a Foreign key error will occur. So I have to delete the existing models and add them again with the new table. So the FK error will be removed.

So can anyone advice on how to overcomes these problems?

The error I usually got when adding a new table to the .edmx file will look something similar to.

```
Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 2186, 2265:Foreign key constraint 'SDOrgPostalAddr_FK2' from table SDOrgPostalAddr (POSTALADDR_ID) to table AaaPostalAddress (POSTALADDR_ID):: Insufficient mapping: Foreign key must be mapped to some AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign key association on the conceptual side.
```

while if I added the table from the beginning then no error will be displayed.
Regards